# Best placement of bridge rectifier to allow DC/DC convertor to become AC/DC convertor. Does this inhibit surge and EMI performance?

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics, emc, ac-dc, emi-filtering

I am trying to use the power supply: CQB50W12-72S12 with AC power without degrading the performance of its recommended filter and surge components. 120VAC peak voltage is 169V and I am worried that this may not work well with the 180V breakdown voltage of the Surge TVS. I am also wondering where the best place for the rectifier is in relation to the inputs of the power supply and filter components

What is the best location for a bridge rectifier to allow this power supply to be an AC or DC power supply? I think the best location is 2 (see pics) since its right before the C4 82uF smoothing cap but I worry that this might affect the surge and EMI filtering performance.

Edit: forgot to mention that I am trying to use the following 3 control powers: 48VDC, 125VDc, and 120VAC

Links to [datasheet](https://www.cincon.com/productdownload/Datasheet-CQB50W12-series.pdf) and [app note](https://www.cincon.com/productdownload/CQB50W12-series-application-note.pdf)

Picture from datasheet of recommended filter and surge TVS diode:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Neither of those locations are going to satisfy the module's input ripple requirements.  The datasheet doesn't state it, but going off of boilerplate TDK Lambda white papers, 10V p-p sounds like a good start.  I would put the bridge rectifier before all of the filter components with a large capacitor between them.  And obviously if this is going to be line powered, don't forget your other safety components.

Comment: Absolute maximum continuous 160V, I don't see any way this is acceptable for direct mains use.

Comment: @TimWilliams what if there were two low value resistors before or after the rectifier to divide the voltage down about 10V?

Comment: You would use resistors to burn excess power? Why use an SMPS at all? ...What's wrong with a proper name-brand off-the-shelf AC-DC converter?

Comment: @TimWilliams trying to have the option to do 48V,DC, 125VDC and 120AC all in one package. this is one of the few DC/DC convertors with such a large input voltage operating window and I figured if we could just put a rectifier we could do AC?

Comment: That would be important design information to include in the question!

Comment: @TimWilliams yeah sorry, added that to the question. but does the resistor divider make sense at least for the time being?

Comment: No, but it might be acceptable to use a more refined version, like a depletion MOSFET voltage limiter.  Which can permit MOV protection at the inlet, which will be far more robust than a tiny TVS.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148777/discussion-between-erv-and-tim-williams).

Comment: @vir like a similar 250V 82uF aluminum capacitor that the application note calls for or more like a large farad x cap?